# regex find and replace multiple chars of different kinds in one expression

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I need to replace all left `{` and right `}` curly braces as well as all percentage signs `%` to their respective HTML entities in a document.

I'm using Sublime Text 2's nice little star icon/button in Find and Replace. I came up with `(\{)|(\})|(\%)` to match the chars I need. There might be better ways, but hey... it seems to work.

What would the replacement string look like for this? I mean *one* expression, not with a programming language.

Basically it's replacing what I find with group `$1` with something and then the same for group `$2` with something else. Here in pseudo-code:

```
    (\{)|(\})|(\%) ==> $1 replace with &#123; AND $2 replace with &#125; AND... etc.
```

Is this possible? I can provide some target sample data if needed.

#### Back story

These three characters can't be placed as is inside an attribute's value in HAML, like

```
:text => "blabliblu {20% lalla...}"
```

etc., without being escaped.

The percentage sign could theoretically be escaped with `\%` but the curly braces can not be escaped with `\{` and `\}`, at least not when i'm preprocessing the HAML with Livereload (Win7). Maybe it's a Ruby thing? Anyhow, I'm going for the HTML entity approach.

Comment: You want one regex to do the work of three regexes. I don't think this is possible with the regexes in sublime text, and don't see why you can't just use three, or some tool actually suited to this sort of work, like sed, perl, python or ruby.